# Most efficient way to take a weighted average

Tags: algorithm, performance

I work on computer simulations and frequently use a weighted average repeatedly inside each agent (object.)  I am wondering if there was maybe a more efficient way of doing it than the way I am now.

Here's some pseudocode to show how I am currently completing the task:

```
Parameters:
x - first value to be averaged
y - second value to be averaged
weight - percent (from 0 to 1) that weighs the values being averaged


Code:
foo = x * weight
bar = y * (1-weight)
return foo+bar
```

I understand that multiplication is a very lightweight operation, but given the nature of simulations (thousands or tens of thousands of agents/objects running the operation frequently) I am curious if anyone else has any ideas.

Thanks!!

Comment: Is `weight` a constant?

Comment: If you do a lot of these with different values, maybe you can use SIMD. That's a global optimization, requiring different structuring of the code and data layout.

Comment: @U.Windl not always, it depends on the application

Comment: Actually I think that memory accesses to get and store the values costs more performance than the actual arithmetic on current CPUs. Are there actual performance numbers on how much the operation costs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid a multiplication:

```
  x * weight + y * (1 - weight)      // 2 multiplications, 1 addition, 1 subtraction
= x * weight + y - y * weight
= x * weight - y * weight + y
= (x - y) * weight + y               // 1 multiplication, 1 addition, 1 subtraction
```

Beyond that we'd need to know a lot more about the surrounding code, the input values, how the result is used, how often the result isn't used, the accuracy/precision needed, etc.

Comment: This is great!  The fact it's more concise is also really nice.  For reference, this is usually used for making a random decision, where x and y are two variables with a probability given by weight.  Sometimes there are more than two options, and in that case I usually tally the weight and then choose a random number inside that total weight, iterate through the options and choose the option the weight corresponds to.  But sometimes there are only two options, and these operations tend to be the most frequent, so thank you again!